# Force razor so that always outputs html

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, overriding

My best guess is to override System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase Write metod so it returns WriteLiteral, but then I can't use @model keywor wich I must use... On sites I do there's no risk at all from XSS attack and I have few thousands variables that I need to display in my view that contain html so I don't want to wrote @Html.Raw for every variable that I wrote... 
And it's not about bad design :))

EDIT: I got it myself
Nevermind, I was overriding wrong method...

```
namespace a
{
    public abstract class View<TModel> : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>
    {
        public override void Write(Object value)
        {
            base.WriteLiteral(value);
        }
    }
}
```

and be sure to modify your web.config INSIDE View folder like this

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="a.View">
```

Comment: This q does not make sense. Please start with a *complete* description of your problem.

Comment: sorry for bad english... The thing is when you put in your view @Variable it will output html encoded Variable, and I want html... now @Html.Raw(Variable) would do the job, but I don't want to write Html.Raw on every variable that I want to output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. Use `Views/web.config` `system.web.webPages.razor/pages[pageBaseType]` to se t it up.

```
public abstract class UnsafeWebViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    public override void Write(object value)
    {
        base.WriteLiteral(value);
    }
}
```

edit: damn, too late :)

Comment: After updating to MVC 4 via VS 2011, this solution throws a System.InvalidOperationException: Stack empty.